# How to make Tikz use a font I've loaded in luatex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I've got the following sample latex file I'm using with luatex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0, 0) circle (3);

    \path[%
        decorate,
        decoration={%
        text along path,
        text={The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.},
        text align=center}
        ] (0, 3) arc (90:450:3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives me the following:

[image]

If I load a font using `fontspec`/`setmainfont`, how do I go about changing the font of the text that's displayed along the path?

And while I'm at it, is there a way to "lift" the text off the circle without having to manually calculate a smaller radius for the text arc? Is there some sort of yoffset parameter I can set?

Comment: The `raise` key allows you to move the text up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you set a font for the document, it will be used in these decorations. You can lift the path up by using the `raise` key.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0, 0) circle (3);

    \path[%
        decorate,
        decoration={%
        raise=8pt,
        text along path,
        text={The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.},
        text align=center}
        ] (0, 3) arc (90:450:3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]